# Is there a function that allows you to listen for console logs in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've tried searching it up with multiple different wordings and on multiple websites with no answer, is it possible, is it not, and if so, how? I need to be able to get code to run when anythign is logged to the console and get what that thing was.

Comment: You can monkey-patch `console.log()` to run your function.

Answer (score 3):

You can override `console.log`'s default behavior:

```js
var log = console.log;

var logs = []
console.log = function(e) {
  log.apply(console, [].slice.call(arguments));
  logs.push(e) //custom code
};

console.log("Hello World!")

console.log('Printed logs:', logs)
```

Comment: I'm still having a little trouble understanding this but so far so good, I guess. Which variable is the text that had been logged (most recent)?

Comment: @bruh The code currently does not store the last logged text. Do you want to do that?

Comment: Yeah, is logs an array of all logged text? If I'm completely wrong it's because I'm used to [] being used for arrays, if that is the case, can't we take the length of the array -1 and get the value of that in the array?

Comment: @bruh You can get the last logged text by using `logs[logs.length - 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the original console

   `var log = console.log;`
2. Monkey patch it i.e. modify it when run and all at runtime
   //use the log instance and `'apply()'` method to apply to inherit it
   //we pass in a date for each call of `console.log()` when using the `original ( log() )`

   `log.apply(console,  [(new Date().toString())].concat([].slice.call(arguments)) ); };`
3. Now everytime we call - log() - we are calling the original
   //to test it do this

   `log('test','this is the original console.log());`
4. This is the patched version

   `console.log("This is the Monkey Patched console.log()!", "More text...");`